# Naming the dyamically generated sheet names in excel in jasper reports

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a requirement where I need generate the report in excel format. Sheets of the excel sheet will be generated dynamically. I wanted to know if there is a way for naming these dynamically generated sheets.Using net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.names.{arbitrary_name} property we can only name the sheets that we know about.For other sheets jasper gives the default name as "Page X" and so on.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically give names to separate sheets by using line element in Page Header or any where.

Note: We can set this property at Element Level not at Report Level,That's why i have used line as element in my Example.

Example :

```
        <line>
            <reportElement x="140" y="17" width="50" height="1">
                <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{TERRITORY}]]></propertyExpression>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a list of reports prepared and added to a JasperPrint list.

Finally, you can set the names of all the sheets in the list as:

```
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.SHEET_NAMES, new String[] {"sheet one", "sheet two",
            "sheet three"});
```

where exporterXLS is an instance of JRXlsExporter class.

Below is a more complete example of what I described above:

```
Connection con = this.jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
Map<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashmap.put("ReportQuery", this.ReportQuery);
JasperReport myJasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(this.reportJRXML);
JasperPrint myJasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(myJasperReport, hashmap, con);

List<JasperPrint> jprintList = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();

jprintList.add(myJasperPrint);
OutputStream outputfile = new FileOutputStream(new File(this.outputExcel));

JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();

exporterXLS.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jprintList);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputfile);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter.SHEET_NAMES, new String[] {"first report"});
exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

Comment: JRXlsAbstractExporterParameter is deprecated class (usage of this code returns `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Can't mix deprecated JRParameter API calls with new exporter configuration API calls.
`). Instead that you can use `jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.names.1", "SheetName1")` etc.

Answer (score 0):

## in iReport Designer

Using iReport Designer you need to follow those steps:

1. go to the properties of your element
2. scroll to the property named 'Properties'
3. click the 3 dots button to open the Properties window
4. click add
5. enter "net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name" in the name
6. tick 'use an Expression'
7. press the button on the right of the value field and
8. pick your field, variable or parameter.

### in the JRXML

if you want to change it in the JRXML file directly you need to find your element and add the following propertyExpression to it (for using a field as the input for your sheet name):

```
 <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name">
      <![CDATA[$F{FieldName}]]>
 </propertyExpression>
```